# How to vertically align text next to an image avatar in ionic?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, alignment

I am trying to place a label/name next to an avatar in a list of items. I am using Ionic v1.

Here's my file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="ionic@*" data-semver="1.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" />
    <script data-require="ionic@*" data-semver="1.3.1" src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

<div class="list">
  <div class="item item-avatar-left item-icon-right">
    <img src="venkman.jpg">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right">
    <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right">
    <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <p>hi</p>
    <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-avatar-left item-icon-right">
    <img style="height: 15px" src="venkman.jpg">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <p>hi</p>
    <i class="icon ion-ios-telephone"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also got it on plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/g3HI56XFZmZwxAGlUcBj?p=preview

If I use an icon then the formatting works great and the text is vertically-aligned next to the icon but for some reason when I use an avatar, the text is always at the vertically always at the top.

How do I vertically align things in the middle with ionic? Should I use flexbox for this?

I noticed that it doesn't automatically align the image in the center if it's a short image as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post, but I arrived here searching how to do something similar, so maybe it could help someone in the future.

A easy way to do that is using a table:

```
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
    <td><img src="venkman.jpg"></td>
    <td><h2>Hello</h2></td>
    <td><i class="icon ion-ios-telephone"></i></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Then with css you can custom the width for each cell to achieve the formatting that you are looking for.